# How do you properly structure case statements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I'm relatively new to programming, and I was wondering how to properly structure case statements. My case statement seems to only be calling one statement, particularly the only one with code in it. I'm calling a random number for decision making for a section of the AI. However, when the number is generated, it seems to only call one statement which is the only one that has code in it. Thanks in advance.

```
NSInteger decisionMaking = arc4random() % 3;

switch (decisionMaking) {

        case 1:

        break;

    case 2:
      self._opponent.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(300, 10);
        [self._opponent.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(10, 100)];
        break;

        default:
        break;
```

Comment: This looks correct, as long as `NSInteger` is defined as an integer data type. But it obviously doesn't do anything in the 0 or 2 cases.

Comment: Your random number will be 0, 1, or 2. Only 2 has code. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: Yeah but its only calling the second case. I was expecting that it would call case 1. However, no matter what, it is only case 2.

Comment: Random number generators typically require seeding, say with the time, to prevent them returning the same sequence every time the program is run. Supposedly, `arc4random()` does not need seeding. To check this out, put something in the other `case` statements. If this is in a program loop. you won't know if other values are returned, because nothing happens.

Comment: @WeatherVane No seeding needed for `arc4random`.

Comment: @foodie101 The empty cases don't do anything so they won't be called. Those empty cases will be removed by the compiler. Add an `NSLog` statement or something and you see they are called roughly 1/3 of the time each.

Comment: Why do you need a random number when there is only one outcome?

Comment: Well, because i want the AI to either dodge or stay still to able to be hit by a punch

Comment: I put something in each, but now it seems all are being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I considered that there were some things not working in the program, such as NSLog not printing, so I made a new project in xcode 6. So, i was using NSLog and noticed that when I tested the case statement, 60 things printed. Then i realized it was because it was calling the method in the update method which performs the case statement 60 times! So, I realized that was why it seemed every things was happening at once. So i fixed it and now it is good. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements are functionally equivalent to a chain of if/else if/else if/else if statements, but more efficient when there are multiple else cases because the compiler can generate code that decides which case to execute with much fewer comparisons.

Since each of your other case statements is an empty break, they do nothing. There's no real point in having the case for 1. The default case will take care of any values that don't have cases to cover them.

The compiler will complain if you have possible values that are not handled but no default: statement, but that' just to make sure you aren't forgetting something.

When you have a switch statement with only one "active" case (one case with code that actually does anything) then there isn't much point in using a switch statement. The amount of code executed is probably about the same, but a single if is easier to read:

```
NSInteger decisionMaking = arc4random() % 3;

if (decisionMaking == 2)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

That is functionally equivalent to your code, but simpler to read.

If you wanted to do something different if decisionMaking was not equal to 2, you could change it thus:

```
NSInteger decisionMaking = arc4random() % 3;

if (decisionMaking == 2)
{
  //do stuff
}
else
{
  //do other stuff - same as the "default:" case in the switch statement.
}
```

It's really only when you get to 3 or more possibilities that a switch statement makes sense.

Comment: I just tried it with if statements, but im still getting all cases, or in this case, if statements, called. Either that or only decisionMaking is always equaling 2... Maybe i need to seed it? But with arc4random() you don't need to...

Comment: What makes you think all your if statements are being called? Add an EDIT: section to your original question with your new code and an explanation of why you think all the parts are being called. It sounds like you have a basic misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Well, when i still as using case statements to call it, for one case, i would NSLog something and for the other, it would move the player. However, i believe both were called, because the log appeared and the player moved. Im not completely sure though because the log appeared at the bottom of xcode, but nothing appeared (this has been happening for a while). Also, i tried it with moving the player with different directions based on the case. They were contradicting directions, using applyImpulse, and it seemed the player was being tugged in two directions and was shaking.

Comment: Usually that means you forgot to end one of the cases with a break statement. If you don't have a break statement the execution of the case with the missing break falls into the next case. The pseudo-code case 1: print "a"; case 2: print "b"; case 3: print "c" would display 1, 2, and 3 if the value is 1, 2 and 3 if the value was 2, and just 3 if the value of the switch was 3.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you don't need `case` statements, you just need a probability, such as

```
if (arc4random() % 3 == 0)  // one third chance (approx, that's another issue)
    dodge();
```

Comment: Still not working and dodge(); is still being called each time

Comment: You haven't posted enough detail about your program. Have you tried counting the number of times you dodge and the number of times you don't, and display the two counts on program exit?

Comment: Ok, after doing it 5 times, the project exited 5 out of 5 times.

Comment: You still haven't posted any code showing what happens when you don't dodge. At the very least, you need to count how many times you dodge and how many times you don't dodge and print both, after 100 loops, and say what chance of dodging there was.

Comment: I figured it out! I considered that there were some things not working in the program, such as NSLog not printing, so I made a new project in xcode 6. So, i was using NSLog and noticed that when I tested the case statement, 60 things printed. Then i realized it was because it was calling the method in the update method which performs the case statement 60 times! So, I realized that was why it seemed every things was happening at once. So i fixed it and now it is good. Nevertheless, thanks for your help everyone!